# Python threading overkill?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing a streaming radio program for use on a raspberry pi which uses an IR remote control. The remote control logic is uses time.sleep() and blocks the main program thread, hence why I've started to use threads.

I feel like I'm going down a rabbit hole with this code, as I'm using multiple globals and queues to manage the state of the remote control and actions that need to be performed. I don't particularly like using globals, so would be interested to know how I could refactor these out.

I'm also firing off new threads for every remote keypress, when viewing the active threads I can see they are being closed, but the thread id is incremented on subsequent threads - is this normal? I would have assumed that if a thread is closed the next id would use one of the previous ids.

Any help would be appreciated.

Code is below - I've excluded the remote control code due to size and have simulated the keypresses instead.

```
import time
from queue import Empty, Queue
import threading
import random

is_priority = False
is_channel_change = False
is_powering_off = False

def poweroff():
    global is_powering_off
    is_powering_off = True
    # no keypresses actioned whilst powering off
    print("powering off...")    
    # save config
    # sudo shutdown now
    time.sleep(5)

def mute():
    print("muting on/off...")    
    # no keypress allowed other than power/reboot
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print("...muted")
    return

def channel_up():
    # allow other keypresses
    # exception: channel up keypress during channel up/down should be blocked - wait for channel up to finish first
    print("channel up...")    
    time.sleep(2)
    print("...channel up")
    return    

def channel_down():
    # allow other keypresses
    # exception: channel down keypress during channel up/down should be blocked - wait for channel down to finish first
    print("channel down...")    
    time.sleep(2)
    print("...channel down")
    return    

# remote ir thread (loop forever)
def remote(queue):
    global is_priority
    # listen for remote keypresses and decode
    keypresses = {
     1: 'power',
     2: 'channel_up',
     3: 'channel_down',
     4: 'mute'
    }

    # Simulate remote keypresses 
    while True:
        rand_wait = random.uniform(0, 3)
        rand_keypress = random.randint(1, 4)
        decoded_keypress = keypresses[rand_keypress]
        print(f'Keypress received: {decoded_keypress}')

        # block putting keypresses on queue
        if is_priority == False:
            queue.put(decoded_keypress) # FIFO
    
        time.sleep(rand_wait)

def consumer(queue):
    global is_blocking, is_channel_change, is_priority
    while True:
        try:
            # Process decoded keypress here
            item = queue.get()
            print(queue.qsize())
            print(f'Action: {item}')

            # if power keypress and isn't already powering down
            if item == "power" and is_powering_off == False:
                is_priority = True
                threading.Thread(target=poweroff).start()      
            # if channel up and isn't already changing channel and no other priority keypresses                          
            elif item == "channel_up" and is_channel_change == False and is_priority == False:
                is_channel_change = True
                channel_up_thread = threading.Thread(target=channel_up)
                channel_up_thread.start()
                channel_up_thread.join()
                is_channel_change = False
            # if channel down and isn't already changing channel and no other priority keypresses                          
            elif item == "channel_down" and is_channel_change == False and is_priority == False:
                is_channel_change = True
                channel_down_thread = threading.Thread(target=channel_down)
                channel_down_thread.start()
                channel_down_thread.join()
                is_channel_change = False
            # if mute keypress and no other priority keypresses
            elif item == "mute" and is_priority == False:
                mute_thread = threading.Thread(target=mute)
                mute_thread.start()          
                mute_thread.join()
            else:
                time.sleep(0.001)

            # output current threads
            for thread in threading.enumerate():
                print(thread.name)

            queue.task_done()
        except Empty:
            continue
            print("empty")        

def main():
    queue = Queue()

    remote_thread = threading.Thread(
        target=remote,
        args=(queue,),
        daemon=True
    )
    remote_thread.start()

    consumer_thread = threading.Thread(
         target=consumer,
         args=(queue,),
     )
    consumer_thread.start()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Updated code based on Async IO:

```
import random
import asyncio

async def poweroff():
    print("powering off...")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("...powered off")
    return
   
async def mute():
    print("muting on/off...")    
    await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
    print("...muted")
    return

async def channel_up():
    print("Channel up...")    
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("...channel up")
    return

async def channel_down():
    print("Channel down...")    
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("...channel down")
    return


def empty_queue(q: asyncio.Queue):
  while not q.empty():
    q.get_nowait()
    q.task_done()

 
async def producer(queue):

    keypresses = {
     1: 'power',
     2: 'vol_up',
     3: 'vol_down',
     4: 'channel_up',
     5: 'channel_down',
     6: 'mute'
    }

    while True:
        try:
            rand_wait = random.uniform(0, 5)
            rand_keypress = random.randint(1, 6)
            decoded_keypress = keypresses[rand_keypress]
            print(f'Keypress received: {decoded_keypress}')

            await queue.put(decoded_keypress)        
            await asyncio.sleep(rand_wait)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
 
async def consumer(queue):
    while True:
        try:
            item = queue.get_nowait()
            print(f'Action: {item}')
            if item == "power":
                # run poweroff method and prevent subsequent actions from being triggered by using await
                power_task = asyncio.create_task(poweroff())                
                fast_val = await power_task
                empty_queue(queue) # not really needed as will be powered off
            elif item == "mute":
                # call mute method - don't need to wait for return
                power_task = asyncio.create_task(mute())                
            elif item == "channel_up":
                # call channel up method - don't need to wait for return
                asyncio.create_task(channel_up())
            elif item == "channel_down":
                # call channel down method - don't need to wait for return
                asyncio.create_task(channel_down())
        except asyncio.QueueEmpty:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
            continue 

async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    await asyncio.gather(producer(queue), consumer(queue))
 
asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: It makes no sense to create a thread if you're going to join it immediately after starting it. The thread is completely wasted in that case. You'd be better off just calling the target function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to look at: are thread a good idea because of the GIL? In this case the worker functions are not CPU bound so threading is in principle a suitable mechanism. (in the sample code the workers are bound in a IDLE or WAIT state waiting for the clock, in real code it will probably be waiting for some I/O event but not CPU bound either.

But where this gets inefficient is that you're constantly spawning new threads.

I urge you to look at `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` (https://www.python-engineer.com/posts/threadpoolexecutor/)

And even better is to rewrite the code into an async ioloop.

Comment: I hadn't considered async io. Thank you! 
I have updated the code above to include the asyncio version - this appears to work very well as a proof of concept. Are there any concerns with the implementation of asyncio within my code?

Comment: This code looks decent at a quick glance. Only one thing catches my eye: why use `queue.get_nowait()` in combination with `except asyncio.QueueEmpty` and sleep? Looks like a simple `queue.get()` would do the same thing.